# key not present error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

From my understanding what should be happening here is explained in the comments but for some reason I get this error in the editor

> KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.String].get_Item
>   (Int32 key) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:150)
>   UpgradeManager.ScanForAvailableUpgrades () (at 
>   Assets/Scripts/UpgradeManager.cs:125 UpgradeManager.Update () (at
>   Assets/Scripts/UpgradeManager.cs:70)

The error happens after the function `DisableSameType` is called

```c#
public string GetUpgradeType(string upgradeName){
        return upgradeTypes [upgradeName];
    }

    public void DisableSameType (string upgradeName){
        string upgradeType = GetUpgradeType (upgradeName);

        string[] keys = KeyByValue (upgradeTypes, upgradeType); //returns all the keys of the same type

        if (keys.Length == 0) { //if there are no keys
            return;             //then return
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++) { //loop through all the keys
                upgradesOwned [keys [i]] = false;   //Set them to false
            }
        }
    }
```

And here are other relevant code

```c#
public List<string> AvailableUpgrades = new List<string>();

    protected Dictionary<int,string> upgradeNames = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    protected Dictionary<string,bool> upgradesOwned = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
    protected Dictionary<string,bool> upgradesPurchased = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

    protected Dictionary<string,int> upgradeCost = new Dictionary<string, int>(); 

    /* UPGRADE TYPES
     * Title
     * Layout
     * Scoreboard
     * VisualCountdown
     */
    protected Dictionary<string,string> upgradeTypes = new Dictionary<string, string>();

protected bool IsPurchased(string upgradeName){
    return upgradesPurchased [upgradeName];
}

public static string[] KeyByValue(Dictionary<string, string> dict, string val)
    {
        string key = null;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in dict)
        {
            if (pair.Value == val)
            { 
                key += pair.Key + "|"; 
                break; 
            }
        }
        return key.Split('|');
    }

protected void ScanForAvailableUpgrades(){
        AvailableUpgrades.Clear ();                                             //Clear the list
        int scanRange = GetUnits() + GameManager.Instance.scanRange;            //Get the range by adding the scanRange to current units
        for (int i = 0; i < upgradesOwned.Count; i++) {                     //Loop through all upgrades
            if (IsPurchased (upgradeNames [i])) {
                //return
            } else {
                if (scanRange >= upgradeCost [upgradeNames [i]]) {                      //Check if the cost is within the scanrange
                    if (AvailableUpgrades.Contains (upgradeNames [i])) {                //Check if upgrade is already in the available list
                        //return;                                                   //If it is we just return
                    } else {                                                        //Else
                        if (upgradesOwned [upgradeNames [i]]) {                 //Check if the user already has the upgrade *NOTE* Should probaby check for this first to improve performance
                            //return;                                               //If it is return
                        } else {                                                    //Else
                            AvailableUpgrades.Add (upgradeNames [i]);                   //Upgrade does not exist and is not bought so add it to the available list
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

after further debugging i have found out that `Debug.Log(keys[i]);` is returning the first string as "basicTitle|" and the string string is blank

EDIT:
I can see where my question can seem misleading line 125 is this line `if (IsPurchased (upgradeNames [i])) {` however Ive already gone through and after commenting out "DisableSameType" the error goes away the method `DisableSameType` is a new function and the error didnt start happening till it was implemented so I am 100% positive this is the source of the error im just not sure what is causing it

Comment: Why not just do `dict.Where(e => e.Value == val).Select(e => e.Key).ToArray();` instead of all that in your `KeyByValue` method?

Comment: because i have no idea how to use Linq @john :)

Comment: Likely the `upgradeName` value is not a valid key for `upgradesPurchased`. That's my best guess. I recommend setting a breakpoint where it throws the error, and checking the values.

Comment: I used johns linq answer it works..I wish i knew how to fix my current code but i guess johns solution would be the more efficient way and thats what matters right?

Comment: an explanation of your answer would be nice @john since i am not familiar with linq

Comment: From the top: Dictionary implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, so we can use LINQ with it. `.Where(...)` filters based on the condition. `e => ` simply states that, when we check the condition, the entry from the dictionary will be called `e`. Next, the `Select(e => e.Key)` states that we want an `IEnumerable<TKey>` by selecting the `Key` from `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`. Finally, `.ToArray()` converts the result into an array of TKey (in your case, string). Note that LINQ is effectively a [view](http://rextester.com/XEEBT99073) - it's enumerated at the time of use.

Comment: i see very nice to know

Comment: Double click the error from Unity editor and it will take you to the exact line of code that error is at. Post that line of code instead of guessing where the error might be. It's as simple as that,

Comment: i stated in my question where the error was?? I wasnt guessing at all i did my debugging and found out as much as i could about the problem @Programmer

Comment: The top of the question said *"The error happens after the function `DisableSameType` is called"* There are many code inside this function and we don't even know which one is causing the issue. It's like a guessing game to me. You seem to be commenting and uncommenthing that function out `DisableSameType` but you don't know and didn't tell us which line is causing it. By double-clicking on it, Unity will show you the exact line the error is happening on.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a valid `key` in `upgradesOwned` dictionary.
Before setting the `key value` to `false`, you should check if the `dictionary` has the `key`. If it has the `key` then you can make it `false`, otherwise you'll need to `Add` a key value pair in the `dictionary`.
So, instead of this line in your code:

```
upgradesOwned [keys [i]] = false;   //Set them to false
```

It should be like this:

```
if(upgradesOwned.ContainsKey(keys[i])){
    upgradesOwned [keys [i]] = false;   //Set them to false
}else{
    upgradesOwned.Add(keys [i],false);   //Add new key and set them to false
}
```

Comment: but if no key exist already then there is a bug already in the code

Comment: Unfortunately you'll probably have to step through the code to find where that bug is.

Comment: @ForgedInFlame I can't seem to find any lines in your code which adds keyValue in upgradesOwned dictionary. But, you are trying to access a value by key in this dictionary, which must throw an error.

Comment: i didnt add that part of the code as i didnt see it as relevant and i prefer not to throw a whole lot of the code online

Comment: Then there is a bug. What I would do, is to print all values of keys array and also all the keys of upgradesOwned before looping through the keys array for making sure all the keys are available in upgradesOwned.